# How to get ECR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY and ECR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, cicd, amazon-ecr

So I've just been handed over to a project using AWS and gitlab. The pipeline was working before but then we moved the organization into another larger organization (Not sure if this is relevant or not).

But I'm getting the error

```
(UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

How do I get the ECR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and ECR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY from a particular IAM User?

Comment: `we moved the organization into another larger organization` How exactly did you _move_ it? The project may have been relying on CICD variables set in the group or project CICD settings. If you moved the project to a different group than where the credentials are set, that might explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the credentials used by the pipeline are not valid.

> How do I get the ECR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and ECR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY from a particular IAM User?

There's no such thing. You should be using `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. Setup an IAM user with programmatic access with the required permissions and then use the credentials associated with said user.

Comment: Yeah, good callout that `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`/access_key are the only variables that are normally used by the CLI/SDK. I'm guessing these are user-defined variables used by the pipeline  to set credentials at particular steps using different sets of credentials. For example, an IAM user used for accessing ECR only, and different credentials/IAM users for other actions. The job may set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` from `X_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` based on the context.